# Performance question - Tabularx or manual column width calculation?

Tags: tabularx, performance

I'm using the `tabularx` package and the provided `X` column type to get dynamic column widths. Since the `pdflatex` run takes longer and longer, I'm wondering whether it would be faster to use an individual calculation, e.g., employing `\tabcolsep` etc. General speaking, is there a "fast" and a "slow" way to achieve dynamic column widths or does everything the same, one time easer to use and one time more cumbersome? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tabularx` is always going to be slower, but depending on your machine and document size that may or may not be measurable in real time. It typically sets the table three times, possibly more if you have a lot of `\multicolumn` commands. 3 times slower is slower, but it might add microseconds or minutes to the actual run time, depending...

If the column widths are knowable in advance then I'd never use `tabularx` but if you have a column spec like `{lX}` then the width of the `X` column depends on the widest entry in the `l` column so to find that you have to pass over the data twice in any case, so you may as well let `tabularx` do it for you.

Comment: I replaced the tabularx stuff with a manual calculation and indeed, it is faster. Thank you!

Comment: @strauberry I'm always happy when people stop using my packages:-)